# Select concatenated: if selected option have value 1, show another select

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, jquery-selectors

I've this problem. I want to show another select only if I choose YES in option, that have value = 1

```
    <select id="select_one">
       <option value="1">Yes</option>
       <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>

    <select id="select_yes" style="display:none">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
    </select>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery("#select_one").change(function() {
    if(jQuery("#select_one option:selected").val() == 1){
        jQuery("#select_yes").css('display','block');
    }

});
```

I tryed to change the css class, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select_one').on('change', function() {
        if ($('#select_one option:selected').val() == 1) {
            $('#select_yes').show();
        } else {
            $('#select_yes').hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tvvef0nd/

**OR**

Shorter way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select_one').on('change', function() {
        $('#select_yes').toggle($('#select_one option:selected').val() == 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
function toggleDropdown(){
  if(jQuery("#select_one option:selected").val() == 1){
    jQuery("#select_yes").css('display','block');
}
else{
     jQuery("#select_yes").css('display','none');
}
}
toggleDropdown(); // check the condition on page load, too
jQuery("#select_one").change(function() {
  toggleDropdown();

});
});
```

Jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/Lo2ou90s/